# Allow empty strings as well as the specified validation assertions

Tags: php, validation, symfony, silex

So I'm using Symfony validation to make sure a posted field is within the given range.
I also want to allow empty string values in this field, for example if the user does not supply any data.

```
'somePostedField' => [
    new Assert\Optional(
        new Assert\Range([
            'min'        => 0.01,
            'max'        => 100,
            'minMessage' => 'tooShort',
            'maxMessage' => 'tooLong',
            'invalidMessage' => 'invalid',
        ])
    )
],
```

You'd think the Optional assertion would do the trick, but that just ignores the rules for the field if it is not present in the data when validating.

How do I also allow empty strings in this field?

Comment: errm. isn't that exactly what you want? If it's not there, it should ignore the rules. If present, then it should run validation against it.

Comment: Erm, yes, but thats not what I asked. "How do I also allow empty strings in this field?".

Comment: @Donal.Lynch.Msc Make the field as not required